# Specialized access control for directories in RedHat

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, acl, access-control

I have a requirement where I want to change permissions for a directory so that the directory owner (user/group) would be able to create files inside the directory and modify them, but won't be able to delete them once they are created. Is that possible to do?

Also, other users should not be able to read,write or execute in the directory and the root should have the permission to delete the directory.

I am using RHEL6.

Comment: It sounds as a job for `selinux` but can't help you with the configuration

Answer (score 3):

In general, UNIX permissions are not that granular.  A person with write access to a directory can create *and* delete files -- both operations write to the directory file.

`selinux` would allow you to specify such a policy. (it'd be akin to swatting flies with a hammer, 'tho)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `richacls` for that. I don't know whether or how easily that is possible with RHEL6.

And it might be necessary to change the directory owner. It should not matter who is the directory owner as long as everyone can do what he is allowed to do, should it?